# HTML5 required attribute not working

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create a email contact form without refreshing the page. So i added jquery im my html file. I used html required attribute ti check if the fields are empty. But when i add jquery code im my html code, the required attribute doesn't work. Below is my code.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML5 Contact Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="styles.css" >

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function(){

$.post("send.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {   
 $('#success').html(response);
 //$('#success').hide('slow');
});
return false;


});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<form id="mycontactform" class="contact_form" action="" method="post" name="contact_form">
    <ul>
        <li>
             <h2>Contact Us</h2>
             <span class="required_notification">* Denotes Required Field</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text"  id="name"  name="name" placeholder="John Doe" required />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required />
            <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message"  cols="40" rows="6" required ></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="submit"  id="submit"  style="cursor:pointer" type="submit">Submit Form</button>
            <div id="success" style="color:red;"></div>

        </li>
    </ul>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I need required attibute to work and also that jquery code to work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation) is only triggered on the `submit` event of the form unless you trigger it elsewhere. Do the AJAX there instead, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mycontactform').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("send.php", $(this).serialize(), function(response) {   
            $('#success').html(response);
            //$('#success').hide('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You are sending the AJAX request when the user clicks on the button, not when they submit the form. Change `.click()` to `.on('submit')` and attach it to the form, not the button:

```
$('#mycontactform').on( 'submit', function () {
    ...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QjPka/