# Why does HTML's "required" attribute work with input type="submit" but not with button?

Tags: html, forms, button, input, required

```
<form action="#" method="get" id="bookForm">
        <div class="field">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" id="title" maxlength="20" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label for="author">Author</label>
          <input type="text" id="author" maxlength="15" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label for="year">Year</label>
          <input type="text" id="year" maxlength="4"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label for="read">Read</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="read" class="button"/>
        </div>
        <div id="form-buttons" class="field">
          <button id="add-book-btn" type="submit" class="button">
            <!-- <input type="submit" value="add"> -->
            Add book
          </button>
          <button id="reset-modal-btn" class="button">
            Reset
          </button>
       </div>
  </form>
```

I have the above form. The first two inputs are required, however it's still possible to submit the form. The attribute only works when input type='submit' is used.

If it helps, I should mention that I have an event handler on the button. It takes the data in the inputs and creates an object. Also, I'm using webpack to bundle different javascript modules.

Try adding type="submit" attribute to button. Added method="get" attribute to form. Rename form's action attribute. Used input type="submit"

Comment: HTML Forms work based on submission. That is, when the form is submitted, the validation occurs, and only if everything is valid, is the submission allowed to proceed. If you go around HTML's submission process, by using script or buttons other than submit buttons, the HTML form process won't occur.... unless you trigger it manually. See [How to detect HTML email input validation with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46553778/215552) for individual fields and [How to use HTML form.checkValidity()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45789010/215552) for the form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 required attribute not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791818/html5-required-attribute-not-working)

Comment: If you omit `type="submit"` from the code above, the default type for a `<button>` is still "submit".  When I test omit that attribute in the code above, the validation is still triggered when I click either button.  From the description it sounds like you have some other code that's part of the overall issue.  Is this *really* a [mcve], or are you trying to ask about some other code?

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey. The issue was caused by having preventDefault() in the code for the event handler's callback function.

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Removing e.preventDefault() from the event handler's callback function fixes the issue.